# Python OpenCV Measurement

Tags: python, opencv

I'm new with OpenCV and I'm trying to mask part of an image which is a lobster claw. I need to remove the knuckle from it.

I'm not sure that I'm heading into the right direction. Currently using a mask with a findcontour feature. But I don't know how I would measure the length and width of the claw only.

[Claw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmBbM.png)

Comment: Do you want measurements in pixels or inches?

Comment: Really it would be in mm, but I'm not worried about that yet.